# Cost of renaming a folder in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to rename a folder in S3 bucket, I understand that rename will run a PUT request which costs 1 cent per 1000 request.

However, the PUT request is defined as a COPY and involves with also a GET

My question is, when we rename a folder in S3 bucket, does it involve copying all sub-folders and files to a new folder with the name I want (which costs more than 1 PUT request), or it just simply 1 PUT request to change the name without touching all the items within the folder.

Comment: The best answer I can see to this is here: http://serverfault.com/a/349813

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In case you've missed it... there are no folders in S3.

The object `/pics/funny/cat.jpg` is *not* a file called `cat.jpg` inside a folder called `funny` inside another folder called `pics`.

In fact, it is a file with an 18-character name: `pics/funny/cat.jpg`.  The hierarchy shown in the console is largely for human convenience, and the ability to create new folders in the console is an illusion, also.

So, yes, renaming a "folder" actually means making a new copy of each object in the "folder," with a change to the object names to look like their are in the path.

This can be done with a `PUT/COPY` request ($0.005 per 1000 depending on the region) followed by a `DELETE` request of the old object (free).  There is no corresponding `GET` request, because `PUT/COPY` is an atomic operation inside S3, so actually downloading and re-uploading the data is avoided.

Comment: Ya I was about 80% sure when I used CloudBerry to rename a folder, the console showed a lot of MOVE request being processed, now I'm 100% sure. Also, how do I know if it costs me $0.005 or $0.01 per 1000 request? (Infrequent Access Requests)

Comment: You could enable logging on the bucket and review the logs to see what calls are being made, and enable detailed billing.