# move S3 files with Glacier storage class to a different folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-glacier

We have a good amount of files that were on the wrong folder in S3 but has since transitioned to Glacier storage class. First thing is we want to restore them so we can move them to the right folders. Once moved we transition it back to Glacier storage class. The main question is, do those files get duplicated on the Glacier side? Since restoring them (to Standard) doesn't mean that they're being deleted or moved on the Glacier side. How do we verify that they are not duplicated after moving to a different folder in the Standard class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon S3 objects are immutable. You cannot "move" objects in S3 or Glacier.

The process would be:

- **Restore** the objects from Glacier storage class
- **Rename/move them:** This actually doesn't happen. Rather, the objects are **copied** to the new Key and then the original object is **deleted**. Using "Rename" in the console does this for you, as does the AWS CLI `aws mv` command.
- Create a lifecycle rule to **transition them to Glacier storage class**

From [CopyObject - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html):

> If the source object's storage class is `GLACIER`, you must restore a copy of this object before you can use it as a source object for the copy operation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, we have the following steps as well where we restore first then move the item to a different folder (to your point, renaming to a different key). So as an added question, there's no way we can rename / move the file to another key / folder without restoring then correct?

Comment: Correct. I've added a reference from the documentation.

Comment: I've tried to move a Glacier object and the copy/move commands are not re-enabled once the item is restored.  This response indicates that it should.  Any ideas on why?  The item is definitely restored.

Comment: @aphenine Can you try using the AWS CLI to copy the object?

Answer (score 1):

The transition of objects to the S3 Glacier Deep Archive storage class can go only one way.

As per, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html:

You cannot use a lifecycle configuration rule to convert the storage class of an object from S3 Glacier Deep Archive to any other storage class. If you want to change the storage class of an archived object to another storage class, you must use the restore operation to make a temporary copy of the object first. Then use the copy operation to overwrite the object specifying STANDARD, INTELLIGENT_TIERING, STANDARD_IA, ONEZONE_IA, S3 Glacier, or REDUCED_REDUNDANCY as the storage class.

To delete the data permananently from Glacier, Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/deleting-an-archive.html

Renaming folder involves cost. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33006139/945214

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the best solution was to delete everything and re-upload.

This is unfortunately only an option if you still have another copy.

Comment: Note: AWS has $0.00 ingress (upload) fees